# Audacity allow to change both bitrate and sampling rate

Tags: audacity

Audacity lets to change both the sampling rate and bit rate while exporting the audio file.Does this mean that after the bit rate change the previously changed sampling rate is changed according to the bit rate ?

Comment: Can you clarify your question? The bit depth (typically 16-bit) represents how many bits are used to store the amplitude of the audio waveform. The sample rate represents how many times the audio waveform is sampled per second. The bitrate usually refers to how much storage space is needed per second of audio.

Comment: Audacity allows to change the Project rate(bottom left) and also the bit rate (during export). Since both are dependent and changing one change the other, which parameter does the audacity considers for the final export ?

Answer (score 1):

Whenever possible, Audacity will export with the "Project Rate" (lower left corner of the main Audacity window) as the sample rate.

For uncompressed file types, such as WAV and AIFF, the bit rate is simply the number of samples per second (the sample rate) times the number of bits per sample (the sample format) times the number of audio channels. For example, for a CD quality stereo WAV file, the sample rate should be set to 44100 Hz by setting the Project Rate to 44100, then the Export format should be set to "WAV (Microsoft) signed 16-bit PCM". This gives a bit rate of:
44100 x 16 x 2 = 1411200 bits per second = 1411.2 kbps.

For lossy compressed file types such as MP3, Audacity will use the Project rate if possible for the sample rate, and the bit-rate will be according to the bit rate settings that you select in the Export dialogue screen. However, very low bit-rate settings for MP3 do not support high sample rates, so if you select a very low bit rate, or a very high sample rate, you will be prompted to reduce the sample rate.